# gzip compression for moodle

Tags: compression, gzip, moodle

I need to enable gzip compression in moodle 2.0.
Is there any settings available in moodle or i need to get any third party extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to turn on gzip via the Moodle admin interface, but you can turn on gzip via editing your.htaccess file or the server configuration.

If you are using Apache, here is a good write on how to enable gzip: http://www.techiegyan.com/2008/10/06/enable-compression-gzip-compression-apache-server-httpd/

Else, google for the webserver and gzip and you should be able to find the right guide to enable gzip.